# How to Access a QT Button (from UI) in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I am a beginner in QT. I want to create a simple GUI to load an image from a file. That's Why I create a button in my GUI, named pushButton (I designed the GUI by QT Creator). Now how can I access the pushButton from my python file?

[image]

**Here is my XML Code (from ui file)**

```
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>OCR</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="OCR">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>567</width>
    <height>332</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>OCR</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>480</x>
     <y>300</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open Image</string>
   </property>
   <property name="autoDefault">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>541</width>
     <height>281</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>522</width>
      <height>262</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Photo</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Here is My Python Code**

```
import sys
import os
import cv2
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class OCR(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super(OCR, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()
        self.show()
        self.image = None

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = OCR()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here, load_ui function load my UI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to access button you just use this in `__init__`:
`self.pushButton + action`

In your code, your class(OCR) is based on QWidget and later you load this widget from file using `load_ui()`. In this solution I didn't manage to access `pushButton`.

If you want to access buttons and other stuff I recommend slightly different project structure. Instead make OCR class based on actual widget.

```py
import sys
import os
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtUiTools import loadUiType

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Form, Base = loadUiType(os.path.join(current_dir, "form.ui"))


class OCR(Base, Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.image = None
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.function_called_when_btn_is_clicked())

    def function_called_when_btn_is_clicked(self):
        print("Button clicked!!!!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = OCR()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this example ui file is loaded via function build in PySide2 > `loadUiType`. All of elements in ui file now can be accessed in `__init__`function via `self.name_of_element`. When you run code code from above, clicking on button will result printing **"Button clicked!!!!!!"** on console. If you have more question, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Hey @Hasan, if my answer was helpful and works the way as you intended, can I ask you to mark my answer as answer to this question or upvote it? I want to get 50 reputation to gain privilege of commenting other peoples post :). I will be so glad for your kindness. Have a nice day and :D

Answer (score 0):

You can access the button by first registering your button using `self.findChild(Class, name)`. I have added it in your code:

```
import sys
import os
import cv2
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class OCR(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super(OCR, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()
        self.my_push_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton")
        self.show()
        self.image = None

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


def print_hello_world(self):
    print("Hello world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = OCR()
    widget.my_push_button.clicked.connect(print_hello_world)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```